# Symfony getenv and env variables escaping

Tags: php, symfony

When setting up an application, I define a configuration value as env variable. The value is present when running `env`

```
REDIS_URL=redis://mypassword@myhost
```

The application does not work. When I copy the exact same value directly into the config.yml file, the application works.

```
dsn: "%env(REDIS_URL)%" // Does not work
dsn: "redis://mypassword@myhost" // This works fine
```

For every other configuration value, it is working, except this one. So is there any escaping to be done when using getenv? Or ENV values?

EDIT : when disabling the password on the redis server, it actually works. Seems to be something wrong with the password.

```
REDIS_URL=redis://myhost
```

Comment: Are you using a password with non ascii characters and the env file encoding doesn't support it?

Comment: No, alpha-numerical characters only. The only thing that might be problematic is the `@` char.

Comment: Try to read REDIS_URL with dotenv component directly. Maybe some issue in dotenv component  version?